# How do I implement "write-behind" in a StatefulActor

Tags: azure-service-fabric

[Azure Service Fabric documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-pattern-smart-cache/) says that:

> Actors provide flexibility for the developer to define rich object
>   structures as part of the actors or reference object graphs outside of
>   the actors. In caching terms actors can write-behind or write-through,
>   or we can use different techniques at a member variable granularity.

In terms of a `StatefulActor` or `StatefulActor<T>`, how would one go about implementing write-behind to improve throughput of state-changing methods?

Comment: That's a pattern  article, not the Azure Service Fabric documentation. Write-behind or write-through refer to what you can do in your code, not specific functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible implementation would be to mark your mutation method as `[Readonly]`, so that the service fabric runtime would not persist the `State` to the cluster replicas. You could therefore modify in memory member variables with the change that you have described and success or failure will be quickly returned to the calling code. At the same time as modifying the member variables, you would register a reminder that will modify the `State` property and hence asynchronously distribute the change across the replicas in the cluster.

You would need to consider the possibility of the actor being moved to a different node before the reminder fires, resulting in read calls to return stale data read from the `State` property before the gets updated.

Comment: Thanks @Darran. Nice idea that makes use of the inherent Actor capabilities.